# pick unique lowest row in unix

Tags: bash, awk

I have a 2 fields in below file.

Field 1 is name and field 2 is transaction date.

I want unique name with lowest transaction date

```
cat abc.lst
John_20130201
David_20130202
Scott_20130203
Li_20130201
John_20130202
Scott_20130201
David_20130201
Li_20130204
Torres_20121231
```

**output desired**

```
John_20130201
Li_20130201
Scott_20130201
David_20130201
Torres_20121231
```

Comment: how is the output sorted? or the order doesn't matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sort -t_ -nk2 abc.lst | awk -F_ '!a[$1]++'
```

or save a pipe and do this -

```
awk -F_ '!a[$1]++' <(sort -t_ -nk2 abc.lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F_ '{ l = lowest[$1]; if (!l || $2 < l) { lowest[$1] = $2 } }
         END { for (name in lowest) print name FS lowest[name] }'
```

(if output order doesn't matter)

Answer (score 0):

this one-liner selects those entries. but doesn't sort the output:

```
awk -F_ '$1 in a{a[$1]=$2>a[$1]?a[$1]:$2;next}{a[$1]=$2}
END{for(x in a)print x"_"a[x]}' file
```

Comment: The first line in more compact form `!a[$1]||a[$1]>$2{a[$1]=$2}`.

Comment: @TrueY Thats pretty slick!!

Answer (score 0):

A pure `bash` solution (not ordered by name):

```
declare -A hash
while IFS=_ read nam val; do
  [[ -z "${hash[$nam]}" || $val < "${hash[$nam]}" ]] && hash[$nam]=$val
done <abc.lst

for i in ${!hash[*]}; do echo ${i}_${hash[$i]}; done
```

Output:

```
David_20130201
Li_20130201
John_20130201
Scott_20130201
Torres_20121231
```

Answer (score -2):

Use the `sort` command:

```
cat abc.lst | sort -u -t_ -k1,1
```

And read about it on `man sort`

Comment: Well, there was also a `bash` tag. Anyhow, I'd replace the `cat abc.lst |` with `<abc.lst`.

Comment: apart from the useless cat, your sort doesn't work correctly anyway.

Comment: `sort` takes file arguments. And you need `-k2` and also `-r`.